# Spring webflow 2 binding: nested object do not follow flow rule

Tags: binding, spring-webflow-2

I have an object that has a nested one that is binded in the same view:

```
class MyForm{
   private String var1;
   private String var2;
   private MyNestedForm nested;
}

class MyNestedForm{
   private String var3;
}
```

and in my jsp:

```
<form:input path="var1" /> 
<form:input path="var2" /> 
<form:input path="nested.var3"/>
```

As I enter some value in var1 and var2 in my form everything goes well (validations, prev/back buttons...) 
But var3 maintain always the last value inserted! Even if I restart the flow from the beginning

Do I missing something?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try in both clases implementing java.io.Serializable and adding a generated serial version ID.

Hope this helps.